# /bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found

Tags: python, django, linux, web-deployment, gunicorn

can anyone help us with this problem I am trying to deploy Django application on the railway but got an error /bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found

**my gunicorn path**

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages

**python path**

['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/drupwn-1.0.3-py3.10.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit-2.0.7-py3.10.egg', '/root/droopescan', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']

I tried to add a path but I am not able to do it. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: PYTHONPATH doesn't matter here. Please provide the output of `echo $PATH` from a bash session owned by the same user. Otherwise, you have two options: 1) add `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages` to `PATH`, or 2) change the command to start gunicorn to use the fully qualified path `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn`.

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Comment: There you go. The `gunicorn` executable's path isn't in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add gunicorn executable's path to the PATH environment variable?

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages`. Depending on how the environment and execution are set up, you may need `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages`.

Comment: But when I am trying to deploy Django appliaction on the railway its still shows
/bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found

Comment: I need more information about your railway deployment and settings. I just deployed a basic Django server via railway Django template and had no issues with gunicorn.

Comment: I also tried deploying a basic Django server via the railway Django template and had no issues with gunicorn but when I am trying to deploy this project from GitHub to the railway on Linux i got an error saying that  /bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found. And when i am tried to deploy from a windows pc I got an error saying that No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin

Comment: You can update the PATH env var in the project's Dockerfile, this will set it in the container and is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 6 months late but this finally might be a question I can actually answer. I'm fairly new to all this and working with flask, not django, so take this all with a grain of salt

That said, I was getting the same error message trying to get a flask application deployed on Railway. Here's what solved it for me:

1.) In your IDE/virtual environment, from the terminal (if you've not done this already):

```
pip install gunicorn
```

2.) From the terminal,

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

to generate/update the requirements.txt file. Make sure gunicorn is included in it

3.) Create a file called "Procfile" in the working directory - the capitalization is important. Also, it must NOT have a file extension

4.) Within the "Procfile", include this one line of text:

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

where "main" is the name of your main python file. So if your main file was named "asdfjkl.py", you'd put this in the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn asdfjkl:app
```

Make sure you have the spaces set up like above

5.) Start a github repo for the project/commit the latest files to it (including requirements.txt and the Procfile)

6.) Go to railway, open a new flask app project, and link to that github repo. Should deploy successfully after that (or at least give a new error message)

I've done this now with 2 different flask apps and that seems to have solved the problem for me. Or at least gotten me to a different log error unrelated to gunicorn. Hope this helps!