# Deploying Flask server in Railway - /bin/bash: line 1: python: command not found

Tags: flask, railway

I've been trying to deploy a Flask server on Railway connected to a React app, the build ends, but the Deploy logs says this:
/bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found

and when i click the deployment url it crashes.

It is connected to this git rep: https://github.com/Itay62/flask-jO4P/tree/main

Procfile contains:

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

requierments.txt contatins:

```
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
asttokens==2.0.5
attrs==21.4.0
autopep8==2.0.1
backcall==0.2.0
bcrypt==4.0.1
bidict==0.22.1
bleach==4.1.0
boto3==1.26.155
botocore==1.29.155
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.4
debugpy==1.5.1
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
entrypoints==0.4
exceptiongroup==1.0.4
executing==0.8.3
Flask==2.2.3
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.4
gunicorn==21.2.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.1.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
ipykernel==6.9.1
ipython==8.1.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==8.0.2
itsdangerous==2.1.2
jedi==0.18.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
jmespath==1.0.1
jsonschema==4.4.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==7.1.2
jupyter-console==6.4.4
jupyter-core==4.9.2
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
mistune==0.8.4
mysql-connector-python==8.0.33
nbclient==0.5.12
nbconvert==6.4.2
nbformat==5.1.3
nest-asyncio==1.5.4
notebook==6.4.8
packaging==21.3
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pickleshare==0.7.5
pluggy==1.0.0
prometheus-client==0.13.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.28
protobuf==3.20.3
pure-eval==0.2.2
pycodestyle==2.10.0
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.11.2
pyparsing==3.0.7
pyrsistent==0.18.1
pytest==7.2.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-engineio==4.5.1
python-socketio==5.8.0
pywin32==303
pywinpty==2.0.5
PyYAML==6.0
pyzmq==22.3.0
qtconsole==5.4.0
QtPy==2.3.0
requests==2.28.2
s3transfer==0.6.1
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
stack-data==0.2.0
terminado==0.13.2
testpath==0.6.0
tomli==2.0.1
tornado==6.1
traitlets==5.1.1
urllib3==1.26.15
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.2.3
widgetsnbextension==4.0.3
zipp==3.15.0
```

(Maybe i dont need all these lines but ive been following this post: [/bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645919/bin-bash-line-1-gunicorn-command-not-found))

Thanks!